# pygame не могу проиграть звук

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, pygame

```
bs1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('1.wav')
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_TAB]:
    pygame.mixer.Sound.play(bs1)
```

не работает и выдает ошибку:

```
bs1 = pygame.mixer.Sound('1.wav')
pygame.error: Unable to open file '1.wav'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего неверно указан путь к файлу.Просто перенеси аудио туда же где и сама програма.И вместо pygame.mixer.Sound.play(bs1) можно использовать bs1.play()

Comment: Спасибки (=⌒‿‿⌒=)